# Set the attribute of a parent element in pure CSS

Tags: css, datatables

Using jQuery Datatables Editor a Bootstrap modal is displayed when editing a row (with no specific classname and attached directly to the body of the page).

I wanted to customize the size of this modal, and did the following :

```
$(".counting_template").parents('.modal-dialog').attr('style', 'width: 90%!important');
```

`".counting_template"` being the class of a field I know will appear in the editor.

It works fine but I would like to improve it by using pure CSS.

I could have done something like that:

```
body>.modal_dialog{

   width:90%!important

 }
```

But my experience was that it was interfering with other existing modals.

Is the a way to do so?

Comment: css doesnt have parent selectors, so you cant do that

Comment: Can you add a class to the modal you are trying to target? or some unique attribute or id? Or you could add a class to `.modal_dialog` and use css to do the styling, so your js is only to add the class instead of modifying the css

Comment: @Huangism as far as my knowledge of datatables goes there is no such option in the bootstrap display controller. Perharps by writing a custom one I could achieve this but it's a bit above my skills

Comment: Can you do `$(".counting_template").parents('.modal-dialog').addClass('edit-modal')` and just use that class in css?

Comment: It will definitively work, at least I'll pull my CSS code in the appropriate location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you cannot target a parent based on a child in CSS, you could improve it a bit by only adding a CSS class in js and leave the rest to CSS

```
$(".counting_template").parents('.modal-dialog').addClass('edit-modal')
```

CSS

```
.edit-modal {
   // whatever you want
}
```

This gives you cleaner js code plus add more flexibility to add more rules if it is needed. Since this class is probably unique (make it unique), you can target it by the class name itself

Comment: Even thought I have numerous tables and modals generated it will be much easier to handle their attributes in a centralized CSS file instead of in numerous js code locations